How to perform process stdin substitution using exec package in golang
I am trying to perform gpg command call in golang using the exec package to create the command.
However, I would like to be able to pass the arguments as if I am using a process substitution such as this one: gpg --verify <(cat ./test.txt.sig) <(cat ./test.txt)
This command does work well, but it's using the files name and I would like to be able to use the io.Reader interface instead to pass the content of the file (i.e. the result of the cat command).
So I tried to come up with the following solution:
VerifyStreamsWithContext(ctx context.Context, sr io.Reader, fr io.Reader) (<-chan bool, <-chan error) {
    okChan := make(chan bool, 1)
    errChan := make(chan error)
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "gpg", "--verify", "-", "-")

    r := io.MultiReader(sr, fr)
    cmd.Stdin = r

    go func() {
        defer close(okChan)
        defer close(errChan)

        out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(string(out), err)
            errChan <- err
            return
        }

        if strings.Contains(string(out), ValidSignatureCheck) {
            okChan <- true
        } else {
            okChan <- false
        }
    }()

    return okChan, errChan
}

However it seems like there is a problem with the content of the second stream since I am getting an error:
gpg: Signature made jeu. 16 mai 2024 09:27:28 CEST
gpg:                using RSA key xxx
gpg: BAD signature from "x x <xxx@x.com>" [ultimate]
 exit status 1
panic: exit status 1

The doc specifies that it should be possible by using "-":

--verify:
Assume that the first argument is a signed file and verify it without generating any output. With no arguments, the signature packet is read from STDIN. If only one argument is given, the specified file is expected to include a complete signature. With more than one argument, the first argument should specify a file with a detached signature and the remaining files should contain the signed data. To read the signed data from STDIN, use - as the second filename. For security reasons, a detached signature will not read the signed material from STDIN if not explicitly specified.


Bash executes this as gpg --verify /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4. Do the same in Go and supply the data for the file descriptors in Cmd.ExtraFiles.

You can use os.Pipe to create "virtual" files. Simple io.Copy from the readers into the write ends of the pipes.

I like @Peter's idea, but one would be aware of two things: 1) /dev/fd/N is not portable (Linux-specific); 2) By default, processes started by Go do not inherit opened file descriptors.

@kostix My code is destined to run on Linux only so it is okay

@Peter I am not sure if I should use the os.Pipe. What you call virtual file, is it a file that will stay in the RAM and be heavily expensive ?

os.Pipe is what | does in a Unix shell. You call os.Pipe and it returns you two "ends" of a created pipe. The read end is to be passed to the spawned process and the write end you use to write data in your code.

@kostix, not exactly Linux-specific. It works everywhere except on Windows.

@Peter, can you please point me to the description of this thing in POSIX (a blog post or something like this would be fine)?

@bragdon, os.Pipe is not expensive. It simply creates a data structure in the kernel.

@kostix, not quite sure what you're looking for here. File descriptors are a basic Unix concept since, like, forever. The docs on ExtraFiles say "ExtraFiles is not supported on Windows." That's all I wanted to point out.

Oh, I guess you mean the specific name /dev/fd/N? I'm not sure where that's specified. I can can tell you that I've never seen it not working.

Looks like it's indeed not posix, but everyone agrees anyway: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123602/portability-of-file-descriptor-links

@Peter I went with your answer and it is indeed working fine thank u. Should I post what I wrote to cloture the question ? Or do you want to post something, so I can put you as the correct answer (even thought kostix's answer is also valid) ?

@Peter, «you mean the specific name /dev/fd/N»—yeah, this ;-) It's the same class of things like /proc/self/exe and /dev/tty, for instance.

You can write your own answer and it's also okay to accept it (you may have to wait a few hours until that's possible).

As suggested by @Peter in the comments, here is the approach that use os.Pipe and file descriptor to perform process substitution:
func (s *Signer) VerifyDetachedStreams(ctx context.Context, sr io.Reader, fr io.Reader) (<-chan error, error) {
    errChan := make(chan error)

    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    // /dev/fd/x represent a file descriptor that is opened while using an os.Pipe
    // 3 and 4 are determined by how cmd.ExtraFiles behaves
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "gpg", "--verify", "/dev/fd/3", "/dev/fd/4")
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout

    // Create a pipe to get the file descriptor /dev/fd/3
    spr, spw, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Create a pipe to get the file descriptor /dev/fd/4
    fpr, fpw, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Pass the file descriptors to the subprocess
    cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{spr, fpr}

    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(fpw, fr)
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(spw, sr)
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        defer spr.Close()
        defer fpr.Close()
        defer close(errChan)

        if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }
        // Important to close those else we get stuck
        spw.Close()
        fpw.Close()

        if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }

        // Dev Note: The output of the command is written on stderr

        errChan <- nil
    }()

    return errChan, nil
}


I guess your code does not work because cooking a single combined input is semantically different from the call using GNU Bash-specific <(command) substitutions: the latter is documented to be presented to the called command as a file name, and one would rightfully expect a call like command1 <(command2) <(command3) to result in the command1 called with two distinct file names—simply because command substitution happens before the (substituted) command is actually called. The called command would then read the content of each file individually.
Hence my take is that gpg --verify - -, when fed a stream combined of the signed data and a signature, merely reads the whole combined stream until its EOF and interprets it as a signed data; the signature ends up being zero-sized (or the other way round—see below). To expect it to behave differently, must presuppose a couple of things:

The command first reads the signed data and then the signature. But nothing should force it to behave like that: the fact the positional argument signifying the data to be checked occurs earlier (leftwise) in the call does not imply it has to be processed first ;-) Sure there exist commands like cat and echo which naturally process their non-option arguments from left to right, but here the arguments designate distinct things and I'm sure gpg is free to process them in any order or even in parallel.
Even if gpg first reads the signed data, and then the signature, in order for this to work, gpg should be able to explicitly tell where in the input data stream the signed data actually ends—as opposed to blindly read until EOF. Honestly, if I were to program gpg, making it read the data until EOF would appear to be a natural thing to do. And even if it would be implemented differently and would stop reading the signed data once its "structural" end is detected, it should have been implemented in a way to not read even a signle byte past that end—in order to make the next read from the stream to obtain the full set of data. While on the surface it might appear to be a no-brainer, it is, in fact, not, as it would preclude the use of buffering or require implementing complicated logic of preserving and transferring possibly buffered data between parts of the program flow which read different data streams. Such thing has to be programmed explicitly, and I beleive, if it would have been, it would have also been explicitly documented as such.

Well, to me, having such expectations to be met is a bit of a stretch ;-)
So, I'd go with os.CreateTemp (known as ioutil.TempFile before Go 1.17)—just make sure you have restrictive umask.

It's indeed a solution but I would like to not have to create a temporary file and do everything on the fly if possible. Or at least to use the less resources monopolizing solution

Do you actually understand that in bash, using <(command) does precisely that: creates a temporary file? ;-) I mean, yes, it would possibly be cool to not use them, but this solution is the simplest, and your fear of using much resouces is, I would say, not really grounded in reality—of course, unless you're optimizing a program which literally calls that gpg --verify multiple thousands of times per second.

Ahh I didn't know that I thought it was just using the provided file after the command.
